# Footer hyperlink to a bookmark doesn't work in PDF document published from Word 2007

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I am writing a user manual in Word that will be published to PDF for distribution to our customers. This document makes extensive use of cross-referencing by way of hyperlinks to bookmarks within the document – which generally works very well. Because this is quite a lengthy document, I have placed a link back to the top of the first 'contents' page in the footer section – with the page number printed on the same line at the opposite side of the footer.

However, I cannot get this link to work in the published PDF document. It looks blue and underlined like a normal hyperlink, but unlike the links in the body of the document, the cursor doesn't become a hyperlink pointer when I hover over it, and clicking on it has no effect.

Any advice on what I can do to solve this problem or work around it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution to this myself. I may as well share it here for anyone else who might come along later with a similar problem:

The trick is to insert a transparent picture, about the same width and height as the word you want to be hyperlinked. I've included one here that's suitable for the word 'Contents' in the font Tahoma 12pt. The size isn't really that important, though, as you can use Word's picture grip handles to resize it to your liking if necessary.

[image: Transparent PNG Image]

Obviously, it's all transparency so it's invisible, but right-click to the left of the white space above this text and you'll see it is indeed an image that can be saved.

Once you've saved the image, do the following:

1. Edit the footer and type in the text you want to link, formatting it in the 'Hyperlink' style if so desired.
2. Insert the picture into the footer – being careful not to click outside the picture until you're finished, as it's really difficult to select again if it gets deselected.
3. Right-click on it and set its text wrapping property to 'Behind Text'.
4. Right-click on it again and set its hyperlink property to point to the location you want.
5. Use the grip handles to position and size the picture so that it exactly covers the same area as your text.
6. Close the Header & Footer editing tool.

One last thing: unlike the other links to bookmarks in the finished PDF document, for some reason this one displayed a tooltip detailing the link location. The only way I could find to get rid of this was to go to "Office button | Word Options | Proofing | AutoCorrect Options… | AutoFormat" and uncheck the option "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks" under the "Replace" header.

Answer (score 1):

Insert as a `Cross-Reference` in to the `footer` (not a hyperlink). 
Use

> References>Cross-reference

Then Select:

> Reference Type 'Heading'

I struggled with this for nearly an hour, then inserted the Cross reference to the '`Heading`' that I had created for Table of Contents.  Create the PDF (don't print) and bingo.

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced this situation, read all suggestions here, but did not find helpful.

I tried myself and solved my problem. Simple, do not make pdf through MS Word, just go to online pdf making sites and convert your doc to pdf.